# Removing a FILESTREAM windows share after uninstall

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2017, filestream

I had to uninstall my local SQL 2017 Dev edition on my home PC (Windows 10) because I changed some drive structure (including where all the system databases lived) a while ago, so I needed to reinstall SQL Server to re-create those system databases (no backups since home Dev instance) and re-set the proper drive paths. I used a configuration file for the re-install process. It seems that when you uninstall `SQL Server 2017` it does NOT remove the filestream share (bug?). So when I get to the install step on filestream, it says

`Windows share MSSQLSERVER already exists and cannot be created for FILESTREAM file I/O. Specify another share name.`

I've tried removing this existing `MSSQLSERVER` filestream windows share from `admin command prompt` by doing:

`net share MSSQLSERVER /DELETE`

But I get an error:

`System error 3 has occurred.
The system cannot find the path specified.`

So how can I delete this existing old `MSSQLSERVER` filestream windows share so I can proceed with the SQL 2017 setup and configure the new filestream share as part of the install process (using the same default `MSSQLSERVER` share name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find this answer on Stack Overflow.

https://serverfault.com/questions/543326/how-to-remove-a-windows-share-when-the-folder-does-not-exist-anymore/543350#543350

I removed the MSSQLSERVER share key from the registry at the below path, and rebooted. The share is no longer there in `net share` in command prompt.

I was able to proceed with my re-installation with FILESTREAM enabled.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`